# Show different values in another column that has the same id pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

How can I show the counts of every unique time under every id and order by id? the ideal result is below.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHlkV.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`groupBy,count`**

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+-------------------+
#| ID|               TIME|
#+---+-------------------+
#|  1|07-24-2019,19:47:36|
#|  2|07-24-2019,20:43:39|
#|  1|07-24-2019,20:47:36|
#|  1|07-24-2019,19:47:36|
#+---+-------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy("ID","TIME").\
agg(count(col("ID")).alias("count")).\
orderBy("ID","TIME").\
show()

#or using time as aggregation
df.groupBy("ID","TIME").\
agg(count(col("TIME")).alias("count")).\
orderBy("ID","TIME").\
show()

#+---+-------------------+-----+
#| ID|               TIME|count|
#+---+-------------------+-----+
#|  1|07-24-2019,19:47:36|    2|
#|  1|07-24-2019,20:47:36|    1|
#|  2|07-24-2019,20:43:39|    1|
#+---+-------------------+-----+
```